# How a python function called and do not wait it finish processing meanwhile that function must be called once. So, thread must be stop

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I am using a script that handle ws requests and response them as json. How ever at the same time those information must be insert/update to DB. But i don t want to wait DB. I should return the response asap. I am using "bottle" in python to do so. How can i reach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer asyncio. However its working on python3. This is the site that i reach. They have good explantation there.
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-asynchronous-programming-in-python-with-asyncio-232e2afa44f6

An this is an example from thier resources.

```
import asyncio  
import time  
from datetime import datetime

async def custom_sleep():  
    print('SLEEP', datetime.now())
    time.sleep(1)
async def factorial(name, number):  
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number+1):
        print('Task {}: Compute factorial({})'.format(name, i))
        await custom_sleep()
        f *= i
    print('Task {}: factorial({}) is {}\n'.format(name, number, f))

start = time.time()  
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [  
    asyncio.ensure_future(factorial("A", 3)),
    asyncio.ensure_future(factorial("B", 4)),
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))  
loop.close()
end = time.time()  
print("Total time: {}".format(end - start))
```